# Taylor expansion in proof of weak maximum principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, maximum-principle

Picture below is part of proof of weak maximum principle. On the red line ,I don't know how to use the Taylor expansion to get $-u''(x_0) \le 0$. I think the Taylor expansion of $u(x)$ at $x_0$ is 
$$
u(x)=u(x_0)+u'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{u''(x_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2+o((x-x_0)^2)
$$
Let $x\in \partial \Omega$ and $u(x)=m$, then
$$
m=u(x_0)+\frac{u''(x_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2+o((x-x_0)^2)
$$
So,
$$
0> \frac{u''(x_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2+o((x-x_0)^2)
$$
then
$$
u''(x_0) > 2\frac{o((x-x_0)^2)}{(x-x_0)^2}
$$
But the $x$ has been choice , how to show $-u''(x_0) \le 0$  ?

Picture below is from the 7th page of [this](http://faculty.math.tsinghua.edu.cn/~lma/lectures/movingplane.pdf) .

> [image]

Comment: Taylor's Theorem is used to establish the [Second derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second_derivative_test) of locating the critical points...

Comment: @Q.Huang  I know the second derivative test. But I don't know what is  the connection with Taylor expansion .

Comment: The second derivative test is proved by utilizing Taylor expansion, you may find out the proof of second derivative test in many textbooks of mathematical analysis.

Comment: @Q.Huang  Thanks.